# ASPX Page and Folder Preview once the ellipsis is clicked in SP13 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, callouts, preview

I need to implement (SharePoint 2013) "aspx" preview for "Site Pages" Library and folder preview (as web page) into Document Library once the ellipsis is clicked. I was able to implement the file "pdf" preview (as "docx") using function callout and, moreover, both "aspx" and "folder" previews but for the Search Result Types.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Attila

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize Callout Control for achieving this requirement.

An idea is using **JavaScript Object Model**. Include the **callout.js** file and call the **CalloutManager** to create the callout.

Demos about how to create custom Callout Control:

http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-create-custom-callout-control-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-custom-callout-menu-in-sharepoint-server-2016/

These demos should also work for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Hi,

 thank you for your feedback. Apologize but unfortunately I'm a beginner, so I don't know how to customize the Callout Control linket to ellipsis to get the preview of non-standard files (different from "docx", "pptx", "xlsx", "pdf", "jpg").
 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Attila